# Android xml CSS like layout margin

Tags: android, css, xml

I want to put  margin in layout xml like html style sheet format

I am using this code and it makes syntax error

android:layout_margin="5|0|5|0dp" and android:layout_margin="5dp|0dp|5dp|0dp"

both are not working. Anybody around here to answer this???

Comment: Read tutorials on building UI for Android first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the following tags instead:

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
```

Comment: you probably mean:
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"